# Using tshark while downloading resource with SFTP protocol, the error is "No buffer space available"

Tags: linux, memory, buffer, tshark

When my tshark program was running in the background, I used the SFTP protocol to download resources on the server. At this time, tshark reported the following error:

```
$ tshark -ni nflog:40 -w capturefile.pcap -b filesize:131072 -b files:120
Running as user "root" and group "root". This could be dangerous.
Capturing on 'nflog:40'
6654 tshark: Error while capturing packets: Can't receive packet 105:No buffer space available
Please report this to the Wireshark developers.
https://bugs.wireshark.org/
(This is not a crash; please do not report it as such.)
```

I checked my memory usage, and the swap space was very big.

```
Tasks:  99 total,   1 running,  98 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s): 34.5 us,  4.9 sy,  0.0 ni, 58.9 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  1.7 si,  0.0 st
KiB Mem :  2047960 total,   662668 free,   936364 used,   448928 buff/cache
KiB Swap:  4194296 total,  4011780 free,   182516 used.   903000 avail Mem
```

I'm wondering why this happened?

Comment: This may be helpful: https://serverfault.com/questions/131935/network-error-no-buffer-space-available

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I'm running tshark on linux...

Answer (score 0):

Buffer size can be modified with `-B` argument, In my case, I increase buffer size from the default 2 MB to 12 MB, and the command used is as follows:

```sh
tshark -ni nflog:40 -B 12-w capturefile.pcap -b filesize:131072 -b files:120
```